# Specify what tests to run from SpecRun command line?

Tags: selenium2, specflow

I'm looking for a way to specify what tests run when using specrun's command line (runtests.cmd).  Is there a way to only run tests with a specific flag or specific feature file?

Or is there another tool for kicking off tests other than runtests.cmd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can filter tests in the Default.srprofile, for example

```
<Filter>@myTag</Filter>
```

will only run tests with the tag @myTag.
More info is provided here: http://www.specflow.org/media/specrun.html#US18